# How to match partly matching filenames from two directories and execute commands on what found

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to match two directories and if the file exists in the second directory, I want to move files from the first directory to a third one.

The filenames do not matching exactly, they get a "_ica" at the end of the name and a different extension.

I have tried to write a script that loops through dir1 checks if it's in dir2 
and if found move to dir3:

```
DATA= /home/eegfilesonlyWM/*
PROCESSED= /home/eegfilesonlyWM/icaddata/*

DONE= /home/eegfilesonlyWM/done/

for f in $DATA ; do 
  fname=${f##*/}
  fname=${fname%/}

 find /home/eegfilesonlyWM/icaddata/ -iname  "${fname*_ica*}" -type f -exec mv {} ./done \; 

done
```

I would like to copy from the first directory those files that already have corresponding files in the second directory.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Directory paths here
DATA=./DATA
PROCESSED=./PROCESSED 
DONE=./DONE

#Do the test and copy here
for f in `ls -1 $DATA`; do
    #build output name
    p="$PROCESSED/${f/\.xxx/}";    #xxx is the file extension of original
    p="${p}_ica.yyy";              #yyy is the file extension of the processed
    if [ -f  $p ] ; then           
        cp $DATA/$f $DONE
    fi
done
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I tried, it does not give me any error, but also nothing happens, I really can't think of anything why.

Comment: Did you update the paths at the start to correspond to your  directories?